# how do i initialize a memory area for a multi dimensional structure array?

Tags: memory, initialization, memset

I have a strcture declared like:

```
typedef struct jpax_egrobstr_s {
    bcm_if_t egr_obj;
    INT32 label;
}jpax_egrobstr_t;

#define     L2_NUM_WAN_PORTS            6
#define     L2_NUM_BYP_PORTS            2
#define     LABEL_T_CNT                 4096
```

with a definition like

```
static jpax_egrobstr_t SW_Egrobj[(L2_NUM_WAN_PORTS + L2_NUM_BYP_PORTS)][LABEL_T_CNT];
```

Now I need to initialize all this area to `-1`, so I chose to do this to inititalize it:

```
#define     MEM_DEFAULT     0xFFFFFFFF
memset(SW_Egrobj, MEM_DEFAULT,
        (L2_NUM_WAN_PORTS + L2_NUM_BYP_PORTS) * LABEL_T_CNT);
```

but turns out, it doesn't really seem to work, I stil find a 0x00 at location [6][0]. why is this? Should the memory not be continous for the structure array.
`CPU: PowerPC`

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `(L2_NUM_WAN_PORTS + L2_NUM_BYP_PORTS) * LABEL_T_CNT` *bytes* of memory with that call. But the structs aren't one byte long.

Multiply by `sizeof(jpax_egrobstr_t)` to get the total number of bytes to pass to memset.